# Probability with Percents

Tags: probability, statistics

A local population consist of 80% women and 20% men. If we select a sample of 20 people at random from this population, then how many woman can we expect to be selected in the sample?

Answer (score 3):

Any random sample from the population will still be $80$ percent women and $20$ percent men. What's $80$ percent of $20$?

\begin{align*}
.80(20) = 16
\end{align*}

Comment: this needs an "in expectation" somewhere. Certainly not every random sample will be 80 percent women and 20 percent men.

Answer (score 0):

To show the answer using formal computation of expected values,

If X is any one person from the population, then all we know from the problem is.
$$ p(X = woman) = 0.8 $$
so
$$ E(\sum_{i=1}^{20}\delta(X_i = woman)) = \sum_{i=1}^{20}E(\delta(X_i = woman)) $$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{20}p(X_i = woman) = \sum_{i=1}^{20}0.8 = 16$$